# Type `never` inferred on this[key] in class constructor

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, constructor, typescript-never

I tried to implement the following pattern

```
type ClassProps = {
  a: number,
  b: string,
}

class Example implements ClassProps {
  public a: number
  public b: string
  
  constructor(props: ClassProps) {
    let key: keyof ClassProps
    for(key in props) {
      this[key] = props[key]
    }
  }
}
```

It compiles and runs just fine as far as I can tell.

But VSCode (`Code - OSS 1.73.0`) raises an error at the assignment because it infers the type of `this[key]` to be `never`.

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I would like to understand why this happens and how to fix it.

The linter is also not clever enough to figure out that a and b here *are* in fact definitely assigned in the constructor and complains about it - but that is easily remedied with the `!` operator.

But for the other error, the only way I found so far to fix it was implicitly or explicitly typing the class properties to any - losing all typing support.

Comment: It's a TS limitation/missing feature, see [ms/TS#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693); the compiler only tracks types here and not identity, so it complains for the same reason it would complain if you wrote `this[key1] = props[key2]` where `key1` and `key2` are both of type `keyof ClassProps`.  One workaround is with generics like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9bJom). Does this fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not,  what am I missing?

Comment: this workaround seems slightly bulky for something that I feel should be concise and elegant.... but it does the trick, thank you!

Comment: There are other workarounds; you could just use a type assertion, for example. Anyway I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: I tried using type assertions on `this[key]`in all sort of ways I could come up with to no avail....I guess because maybe never cannot be asserted to something else? or perhaps I was doing it wrong..

Comment: The compiler will only view the assignment as safe if the value is safe for all possible values of `key`, which would need to be `string & number`, which is `never`.  You can [assert that if you want](https://tsplay.dev/w8BA0m).  It's not much better than `as any`, though.  The point is ms/TS#32693.  You can choose convenient-but-unsafe or safe-but-tedious (which would look like `this.a = props.a; this.b = props.b;`), but nothing perfect exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation or missing feature of TypeScript.  The specific problem with copying a property between two objects of the same type is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693), but the general problem is the lack of support for "correlated unions" as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  If you look at the assignment

```
this[key] = props[key]; // error!
```

The compiler essentially analyzes only the *types* of these values, and not their *identities*.  On the right hand side, it sees you indexing into a `ClassProps` with a [union-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) key of type `"a" | "b"` for reading (also known as the "source"), and thus you have a value of type `string | number`.  On the left hand side, it sees you indexing into an `Example` with a union-typed key of type `"a" | "b"` for *writing* (also known as the "target").  For that to be considered safe, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), it requires the target to be the [*intersection*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the relevant property types: so it must be of type `string & number` (which is immediately reduced to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), since there are no values which are both `string` and `number` at the same time).  And since `string | number` is not assginable to `string & number`, the compiler issues an error.

That error would be completely reasonable if you were faced with the following assignment instead:

```
declare const key1: keyof ClassProps;
declare const key2: keyof ClassProps;
this[key1] = props[key2]; // error!
```

After all, you can't write a random property from `props` to a random property in `this`.  What if you are reading a `string` and writing to a `number`?

And, sadly, the compiler does not distinguish between that case and `this[key] = props[key]`.  It doesn't realize that the types on either side of the assignment are *correlated* and cannot possibly be mismatched.

---

Until and unless anything changes here, we need to use workarounds, or to refactor.  The recommended refactorings usually involve [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  One exception to the union-source-to-intersection-target rule is if the source and intersection are both identical *generic* types.  So instead of `key` being of type `keyof ClassProps`, you can make it of type `K extends keyof ClassProps`.

For example, if you refactor to a generic function like:

```
function copyProp<T, K extends keyof T>(target: T, source: T, key: K) {
    target[key] = source[key]; // okay
}
```

That compiles because both sides of the equation are type `T[K]`.  And then you can call this function:

```
constructor(props: ClassProps) {
    let key: keyof ClassProps
    for (key in props) {
        copyProp(this, props, key); // okay
    }
}
```

If you don't want to spend time refactoring, you could just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on with your life:

```
this[key] = props[key] as (string & number); // okay
```

It's up to you and what your use case is.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IAoCcD2YlQLxQDeAUAJAIBcUAdgK4C2ARhOgDRmNVLDoCW1Ac3YBfYsQDGiFFACiADwT0wcaLyUr6EasFzxkaLDiJkwtRnF7ioCAIRU6TFibMWrjO1G59BY0uMzUXrTiwJjoABRghkhUeigY2EgAlMakpCrAUADWECBUOSCYAGawUgaJZKRFYVDhBVD8UFGJKSRpftggCWDhwAAWvEisTdHDBUkA3JWk-YMA2gUAuvgjiQu5y8i1XvwCUABkNAzM6JOVoqSiosRFtNQhvAFQ-mBdhgA8ACrDANJQEHJgFoACa4ArFKCfAB8vQQ6AEEGAVG+nkwtHQ4ggyLGuSoP1aZGAcIRwHWIGWBCQaIxEDJiymwiAA)

Comment: thank you very much for this very detailed and enlightening answer! But if I may have one more question: In my code I simplified your generic function to `copyProp<T>(target: T, source: T, key: keyof T)` and it seems to work just fine. Is there an advantage to include the second type variable with `extends`?

Comment: I don't know about "advantage".  I would use the constrained generic personally since the unsoundness is less easily exploited that way (in general, not really directly here), but in this particular case it doesn't matter much.  I could change my answer to use that if you prefer, or we can keep it as-is.

Comment: I should have better asked about difference rather than advantage, just to understand. But no need to change your answer, I would accept it multiple times, if I could.